# How many cusps/corners can a convex function have?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, convex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a convex function. How many cusps (sharp corners) could it have? Are them numerable or not?

I could say that they are infinite and numerable, thinking to a function like $f(x)=\arcsin\bigg(\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{2} - \cos x}\bigg)$, which is not convex. If I am right, how to prove it?

Comment: what do you mean by sharp corner (specifically: what does sharp mean)? Would you call the behavior of  the graph of $f(x) =\frac{1}{n} |x|$, $n >1$ at $x=0$ a sharp corner, or would you require a slope $>1$, for example?

Comment: The $f(x)$ you have defined is good

Comment: why would they be infinite?

Comment: Cusps and corners are two different things, at cusps the tangent is vertical, and a convex function defined everywhere on $\mathbb{R}$ has none. If it is only defined on an interval it can have at most two, at the endpoints, because it is one sidedly differentiable at every point of the interior. But there can be infinitely many corners, just integrate the [Cantor's staircase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function).